# Populate dropdown list from another dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to populate a select menu based on the value selected on another select menu.

So far, I managed to get the value and my PHP code does return the values as JSON. However, I can't seem to figure out how to show the data in the next select menu.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="laptopBrand">Laptop Brand</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="laptopBrand">
        <?php foreach($laptop_brands as $laptop_brand): ?>
            <option value="<?= $laptop_brand['Lbrand'] ?>"><?= $laptop_brand['Lbrand'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="laptopSeries">Laptop Series</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="laptopSeries">
    </select>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#laptopBrand").change(function(){
    var lbrand = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: 'laptopSeries='+lbrand,
        url: 'includes/fetch.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            var a = JSON.parse(json);
            alert(a);
            var $el = $("#laptopSeries");
            $el.empty(); // remove old options
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
            $.each(json, function(value, key) {
                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", value).text(key));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if($_POST){
        $laptopSeries = $_POST['laptopSeries'];
        try{      
           $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT `Lseries` FROM `laptop` WHERE `Lbrand` = '$laptopSeries'");
           $stmt->execute();
           $series = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

           foreach ($series as $series) {
                $array = array($series['Lseries'] => $series['Lseries']);
                echo json_encode($array);
            }

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using `->prepare()`/`->execute()` then you should really be using placeholders to prevent sql injection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @Sean Thanks for pointing out. I know I should be using binParam(). But for now that's not my main concern as I'm trying to figure the dropdown out.

Comment: where's this coming from first? `$laptop_brands` or is it not relevant?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am polutlating the first dropdown menu, but it's not really relevant as the second dropdown is the problem. I did a network inspection and the response is returned fine, it's just not showing up on the second dropdown. It's probably something wrong on the Javascript that shows the json data.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this and make sure your server code return exactly what you want to fill in key and value.

```
$.each(a,function(key, value)  // a or jsondata
```

{

```
$select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
```

});

Comment: It seems to be similar to what I did. This doesn't help much